# Вывод результата в порядке убывания

Tags: python, сортировка, сравнение

Программа использует поиск по частичному совпадению *(библиотека FuzzyWuzzy)*, чтобы выводить из json похожие слова на то, что введено в `input()`. Код программы:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

p_num = {
    "num_list_1": {
        "list_1": {
            "1": {
                "name": "Окошко",
                "row": "9.02"
            },
            "2": {
                "name": "Зимний",
                "eff": "7"
            },
            "3": {
                "name": "Меткий",
                "up": "21"
            },
            "4": {
                "name": "Кошка",
                "row": "17.3"
            },
            "5": {
                "name": "Синий",
                "eff": "19"
            },
            "6": {
                "name": "Иний",
                "eff": "2"
            },
            "7": {
                "name": "Мелкий",
                "up": "3"
            },
            "8": {
                "name": "Крошка",
                "row": "8,6"
            },
            "9": {
                "name": "Елки",
                "up": "9"
            }
        }
    }
}
p_num_input = input()
p_num_list = p_num["num_list_1"]["list_1"]
for key in p_num_list:
    p_num_name = p_num_list[key]["name"]
    p_num_fuzz = fuzz.ratio(p_num_name.casefold(), p_num_input.casefold())
    if p_num_fuzz >= 70:
        print(f"{p_num_name} - {p_num_fuzz}")
```

Когда я ввожу в `input()` слово `кошка`, то мне выдает такой результат:

```
>> кошка
Окошко - 73
Кошка - 100
Крошка - 91
```

Слева **слово из таблицы**, справа через тере **вероятность совпадения**.

Мне нужно, чтобы **вероятность совпадения** выводило в порядке убывания. Т.е. нужен такой результат:

```
>> кошка
Кошка - 100
Крошка - 91
Окошко - 73
```

Еще как пример, чтобы при вводе `иний` - выводило так:

```
>> иний
Иний - 100
Синий - 89
Зимний - 80
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Комментарии в коде

```
p_num_input = input()
p_num_list = p_num["num_list_1"]["list_1"]
buffer = []  # создаем пустой список для хранения результатов
for key in p_num_list:
    p_num_name = p_num_list[key]["name"]
    p_num_fuzz = fuzz.ratio(p_num_name.casefold(), p_num_input.casefold())
    if p_num_fuzz >= 70:
        buffer.append((p_num_fuzz, p_num_name))  # добавляем в список кортеж (процент,название) - именно в таком порядке, чтобы проще сортировать далее

for p_num_fuzz, p_num_name in sorted(buffer, reverse=True): # сортируем список кортежей (ключ сортировки по умолчанию - первый элемент кортежа, т.е. процент) по убыванию процентов и итерируем по нему
    print(f"{p_num_name} - {p_num_fuzz}")  # выводим
```

```
кошка
Кошка - 100
Крошка - 91
Окошко - 73
```